# Jquery IE issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

I've an application written in Java and a webapp associated written essentially with javascript. I was running on IE7 and had no issues. But lately, I upgraded to IE8, and since then I've encountered a lot of problems...
No matters which versions of jquery i used, it crashes. I don't have any javascript error messages, but CSS and other methods are not been used...
I found here on StackOverflow a guy with a similar problem, he added this to his header : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`
Indeed, it works for me, but i do not know what that changes on my page. Does this meta change the interpretation of the CSS only ? Javascript ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: This needs much more specific info. What kinds of things exactly happen? What do you mean by "crashes"?

Comment: The problem is most likely in your javascript. Start by taking things out until it doesn't crash again and then further isolate the problem. It's most likely not jQuery code, but you

Comment: Thanks for such explanation...It would be strange that my javascript on IE7 works perfectly fine, but don't on IE8... I'm going to look further about that, but I doubt IE is innocent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X-UA-Compatible` is Microsoft's answer to making IE switch rendering modes for a site. The main issue that companies have with upgraded their IE installs is compatibility with web applications built to run on older versions of IE. This meta flag is used to tell newer versions of IE how they should process the current document.

In your example, the `X-UA-Compatible` value is telling IE to emulate IE7 rendering. If a user visited your site using IE8, it will see this flag and switch to IE7 compatibility mode and mimic its capabilities. You can read more about this at [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

However, if your JS is breaking in a browser then you should fix it rather than relying on this sort of cheap hack (in my opinion). While useful for quickly patching the issue you can't guarantee that it will always work, and you may encounter issues in other browsers that do not understand `X-UA-Compatible` which is proprietary to IE.

If you struggle to fix your problem at the source, perhaps you can post a new question here for the SO users to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The meta you just added tells IE to use the javascript and rendering engine of IE7, even if it's a newer version of the browser. MS implemented such header to avoid breaking sites that depended on a particular behavior of that version. As Evert mentions, it's most probably an error in your code, but withoug having any more info is hard to say what's the origin. I would open IE's debugger (F12) and try to get to the line that's "crashing".

If CSS is also failing (not loading), check the routes you are using to link to the CSS/JS files. Something like using '\' instead of '/' in the path might work in IE6/7 but not in newer versions (as they are much more strict), and the same could happen with unescaped characters. Also, check that your app is serving the files with the correct content/type.

Answer (score 0):

When IE sees the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, it uses it to determine the rendering mode for the page.

IE8 comes with a built-in backward-compatibility mode which allows it to fall back to rendering the pages in IE7 mode. This meta tag is what IE uses to tell it to use this mode.

The idea is that if your page worked in IE7 but not in IE8, then adding this tag would allow your page to continue working when users upgrade.

In general, this is true, but it's worth pointing out that the IE7 mode in IE8 is not identical to a genuine IE7 browser: it has some quirks and bugs of its own which do not appear in IE7.

In addition to specifying the rendering mode in a meta tag, it is also possible to specify it from within the browser. In IE8, if you press F12 to get the developer tools window, you can change the rendering mode from here. This allows you to see which mode a site is using. It will also allow you to test whether changing the mode will help, without having actually add the meta tag. IE8 also has a config setting which can specify to default to IE7 mode for intranet sites, again without needing a meta tag.

However, after all that, I would also say that the compatibility mode is probably not the best approach to solving your problem. You state that the application is crashing. You haven't really described the crash in enough detail for me to diagnose it here, but you do mention JQuery. The one thing about JQuery is that is is explicitly designed to work in all versions of all browsers; I would be interested to see exactly what is going wrong here, but I doubt that JQuery itself is at fault.

Please provide a bit more info about your errors, and maybe we'll be able to help you (I'd suggest starting a fresh question for it though, since the topic will be quite different to this one).